# VirtualBox Ubuntu no longer reading from boot medium

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I've been using a Ubuntu VirtualBox machine for the past couple of months. Today, I logged on as normal and started programming, but when I first logged on there was some pop-up related to VBoxGuestAdditions. I wasn't sure what that was about, so I ignored it, finished my work, and shut down the VM. The next time I went to start the VM, I got the following message while booting:
FATAL: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted.

I can no longer use the VM. I've been searching various forums for help but haven't found anyone else with a similar issue where the error occurred *after* the VM had already been running fine for a long time. I didn't knowingly change any settings or update anything, so I'm a little baffled why my VM no longer works.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully you have a good, working backup of whatever you have done that you don't want to have to do again.

Comment: Fortunately, the important things have been backed up, but reinstalling everything on a new VM would take a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a decent solution, but I did not figure out what caused the first VM to fail. Since the virtual hard disk file (.vdi, containing all of the files I cared about) still existed, I created a new Linux-Ubuntu VM, but instead of creating a new virtual hard disk, I associated the new VM with the old hard disk file. I had to also redo some setting for shared folders and the like on the new VM, but all of my old files are there, so it's not a huge deal.

The .vdi file from my old VM was stored in C:\Users[myUserName]\VirtualBox VMs[myVMComputerName].